# Media queries and bootstrap modals?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a modal and I want it to be able to look good on all devices but currently I am trying the media query below and it changes on all devices ( MBP, iPhone 6, 24 inch Desktop )

```
.modal-wide{
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 90vh;
  /*height: auto;*/
}

/* For mobile phones: */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .modal-body {
    position: relative;
      max-height: 200px; 
      overflow-y: auto;
  } 
  .modal-wide {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

My thoughts was it would only change on my iPhone? but this isn't the case? Have I done something wrong? It is the `.modal-wide` selector styling that is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have this the wrong way around. `min-width: 480px` will target all devices with a screen width of 480px or *greater*. For small devices you want `max-width`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
```